# i ran this command " sudo rm -r -f /home/fille/Desktop/"

Tags: sudo, delete, error-handling, trash, rm

i ran this command " sudo rm -r -f /home/fille/Desktop/" desktop is gone including the trash bin and i get this error when i try to create a new folder from my desktop," see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0Uey.jpg) ", how do i fix this?

[image: error message]

Comment: alright thanks it's all back to normal now.

Comment: Please "accept" the anser that helped you: click the green checkmark next to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new Desktop directory. You should then be able to create new Desktop links, directories, etc.

```
mkdir -p /home/$USER/Desktop
```